# Is there a resolution for Application Insights using a wildcard in CORS headers?

Tags: azure-application-insights, appinsights

I'm running an aspnet core 7 application that uses the Application Insights SDK. I noticed the following warning in Chrome and Edge recently.

[image]

I've tracked it down to app insights using the wildcard symbol in CORS headers. Is there any fix for this?

Comment: So u are using Application Insights SDK on a client side? like an angular app for example?

Comment: @devlife Hope this helps `az webapp cors add --resource-group myResourceGroup --name <app-name> --allowed-origins 'http://localhost:5000'` respective localhost

Comment: @DA Specifically we are using the azure-maps-control package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-maps-control. It looks like it is initiating the call (presumably to track usage, etc).